# NextJS production serverside rendering state not updating

Tags: reactjs, next.js

so in NextJS production my React project with server side rendering and revalidation set to 1s isn't updating state with the refresh of the page, so basically I server side render a page and then I also need to fetch the API to get the latest values from database which causes my site to first display an old value and then flicker to new value, quite annoying...
Does anyone know how to fix this in code?

This is get static props:

```
  export async function getStaticProps() {
      const response = await fetch(`link`);
      const data = await response.json();
    
      return {
        props: {
          data: data,
        },
        revalidate: 1,
      };
    }
```

This is useEffect on page load:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        fetchNewData(); //function to fetch an API
        if (error === null) setLoading(false);
      }, []);
      if (loading) return "Loading...";
      if (error) return "Error!";
```

Comment: _"revalidation set to 1s isn't updating state with the refresh of the page"_ - The contents of the page will not be updated on the first request after the `revalidation` period has passed, that will only trigger the regeneration. The following request will then get the updated page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [useSWR](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs) hook instead of useEffect

```
npm i swr
```

Code:

```
 import useSWR from 'swr'
    
    function Profile() {
      //your API path
      const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/user', fetcher)
    
      if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
      if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>
      return <div>hello {data.name}!</div>
    }
```